# how to android textview marquee getDuration?

Tags: android, textview, marquee

I have time many try TextView marquee animation scroll
need marquee animation duration, finish Listener
plz help me...

1. marquee scroll time
2. marquee scroll finish point or interface listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create animation and animation time like this in `anim` `res/anim/marquee.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="10000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

and call it where you are using your `textView`

```
 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
 Animation marquee = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.marquee);
 myTextView.startAnimation(marquee);
```

Comment: I will try your method tmrw, 'cuase today is National holiday. Thank u for answering my question, Have a good day ! : )